# Having truble opening file using a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that let's you edit a text. Most of it is working fine, but the part that is supposed to open the file and print it doesn't work, as soon as it receives input it closes itself.

```
    while True:
        nom_pac = input("Escriba el nombre del paciente: ")
        nom_arch = str(nom_pac + ".txt")
        arch_abierto = open(nom_arch,"r+")
        for line in nom_pac:
            print(arch_abierto)

#More code

        term_prog = str(input("""Desea cerrar el programa?
        (si/no) """))
        if term_prog=="si":
            quit()
        elif term_prog=="no":
            print("""



                """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So looking at your code and help from Google translate, I can see that you're trying to read a patient's name as input and then create a text file using that name.
This will create a new text file for each entry - is that's what you want?

Also, when using the `for` loop to read the file, you specify `nom_pac` which is the name input by user. This should be `arch_abierto` instead.

```
for line in nom_pac:
    print(arch_abierto)
```

## Correct usage:

```
for line in nom_arch:
    print(line)
```

Comment: @whoever's down-voting the answers, please leave a comment explaining what was wrong. We might learn from it.

As newer members of the community trying to help out, it would be more encouraging for us if you can guide us towards better answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to print the contents of the file entered via the user input. You can do this simply by:

```
nom_pac = input("Escriba el nombre del paciente: ")
nom_arch = str(nom_pac + ".txt")
print(open(nom_arch).read())
# Other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `nom_pac` to `arch_abierto` in for loop and the print as well.

```
while True:
    nom_pac = input("Escriba el nombre del paciente: ")
    nom_arch = str(nom_pac + ".txt")
    arch_abierto = open(nom_arch,"r+")
    for line in arch_abierto:
        print(line)

    term_prog = str(input("""Desea cerrar el programa?
    (si/no) """))
    if term_prog=="si":
        quit()
    elif term_prog=="no":
        print("""



            """)
```